# Why does SELECT FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats returns two rows/table?

Tags: sql-server

Why when I do this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TestTableName')
```

Do I get *two* records rather than one?

I'm planning to use last_user_update to determine if some locally cached data from a previous call to the query is current or if it may be outdated because the table has changed.

The last_user_update column is identical in both records this query returns. Can I just use the value in the first record, or might they differ?

See screen capture below for results:

[image: Screen Capture of results]

```
DatabaseName    last_user_update    database_id object_id   index_id    user_seeks  user_scans  user_lookups    user_updates    last_user_seek  last_user_scan  last_user_lookup    last_user_update    system_seeks    system_scans    system_lookups  system_updates  last_system_seek    last_system_scan    last_system_lookup  last_system_update
TestTableName 2016-04-27 07:53:51.740   5   939150391   1   0   101556  101557  6   NULL    2016-04-28 07:27:17.933 2016-04-28 07:27:17.927 2016-04-27 07:53:51.740 0   3   0   0   NULL    2016-04-27 07:52:49.203 NULL    NULL
TestTableName   2016-04-27 07:53:51.740 5   939150391   2   101559  3   0   6   2016-04-28 07:27:17.927 2016-04-26 17:31:21.200 NULL    2016-04-27 07:53:51.740 0   1   0   0   NULL    2016-04-27 18:21:53.977 NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The indexid of 1 represents the clustered index.

The indexid of 2 is a non clustered index.

You might also see an indexid of 0 if the table is structured as a heap (no clustered index) this isn't actually an index but operations against it are shown in this view anyway.

Regarding your secondary question does the non clustered index cover all of the columns you are interested in? If you just care if *any* column is updated you might as well just look at the row for the clustered index as it isn't possible for any update to affect the NCI but not the CI.

You may get false positives though with your approach as this column just shows the last time an execution plan was executed containing an operator that can update this index, not that an update definitely occurred. Also the values will be null after service restart or the database is set offline (as can happen with auto close).

Comment: Also, your screen capture shows an Index_id of 1 which is a clustered Index

Comment: @Shaneis I didn't look at that. I read the text underneath and looks like I saw the 0 which belongs to the next column. Thanks, edited.

Comment: +1 for "shows the last time an execution plan was executed containing an operator that can update this index, not that an update definitely occurred. Also the values will be null after service restart or the database is set offline (as can happen with auto close)."

Comment: @TheGameiswar thanks. More details on that here BTW https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2008/10/30/what-is-the-difference-between-sys-dm_db_index_usage_stats-and-sys-dm_db_index_operational_stats/